# Unable to decipher nvlink error

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I'm attempting to build a project with `nvcc`. I am getting the most vexing `nvlink error:` messages I've ever seen.

Here is the link statement:

```
nvcc    -rdc=true -arch=sm_21 -O3 -Xcompiler -fPIC -I"/usr/local/ACE_wrappers" -I"/usr/local/ACE_wrappers/TAO" -I"/usr/local/DDS" -I"/usr/include/Qt" -I"/usr/include/QtCore" -I"/usr/include/QtGui" -I"../../include" -I"../../include/DDS" -I"../../include/CoordinateTransforms" -I"../../include/DDS/IDLBrokerTemplates" -I"../../def/IDL" -I"../../def/CMD" -I"../../def/XSD" -I"../../src/NetAcquire" -I"/usr/local/ACE_wrappers/TAO/orbsvcs" -I"/usr/local/include/lct.7.5.4" -L"." -L"/usr/local/ACE_wrappers/lib" -L"/usr/local/DDS/lib" -L"/usr/lib64" -L"/usr/local/lib64" -L"../../def/IDL/lib" -L"../../def/XSD" -L"/usr/local/lib" .obj/../../src/Component.o .obj/../../src/COM.o .obj/../../src/DDS/EntityManager.o .obj/../../src/IDLBrokerTemplates/CommandManager.o .obj/../../src/IDLBrokerTemplates/OptionManager.o .obj/../../include/ApplicationProcessStateReporter_moc.o .obj/../../src/Application.o .obj/../../src/CoordinateTransforms/Site.o .obj/../../src/CoordinateTransforms/Geodesy.o .obj/../../src/CoordinateTransforms/Earth.o .obj/../../src/CoordinateTransforms/StateVector.o .obj/../../src/CoordinateTransforms/KeplerianImpact.o .obj/../../src/CoordinateTransforms/GeodeticPosition.o .obj/../../src/IDLBrokerTemplates/MeasurandSubscription.o .obj/../../src/NetAcquire/NetAcquire.o .obj/DataLossFlightTimeImpl.o .obj/DataLossFlightTime.o .obj/DftTable.o .obj/OptionListener.o .obj/PrimaryListener.o .obj/MissionTimeListener.o .obj/DeadMan.o .obj/main.o .obj/../../src/XML/spline.o .obj/../../src/XML/FpTable.o -l"naps-x86_64" -l"naio-x86_64" -l"nalct-x86_64" -l"curl" -l"TAO_Messaging" -l"TAO_Valuetype" -l"TAO_PI_Server" -l"TAO_PI" -l"TAO_CodecFactory" -l"TAO_CosNaming" -l"armadillo" -l"boost_filesystem" -l"boost_system" -l"xerces-c" -l"jarssXSD" -l"OpenDDS_Tcp" -l"JARSSRTv10" -l"QtNetwork" -l"fontconfig" -l"QtGui" -l"QtCore" -l"OpenDDS_Rtps_Udp" -l"OpenDDS_Rtps" -l"OpenDDS_Multicast" -l"OpenDDS_Udp" -l"OpenDDS_InfoRepoDiscovery" -l"OpenDDS_Dcps" -l"TAO_PortableServer" -l"TAO_AnyTypeCode" -l"TAO" -l"ACE"  -o "DFT"
```

And I'm getting

```
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZN5JARSS15KeplerianImpactC1ERKdS2_S2_S2_S2_S2_'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZNK5JARSS15KeplerianImpact9getStatusEv'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZNK5JARSS15KeplerianImpact13getImpactTimeEv'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZNK5JARSS15KeplerianImpact11getPlhStateEv'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZN5JARSS15KeplerianImpactD1Ev'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZN5JARSS7Geodesy12EFG2GeodeticERKdS2_S2_PdS3_S3_'
```

I'm certain that these functions/files are included in the compile. You can see from the compile that `KeplerianImpact.cpp` and `Geodesy.cpp` are in there.

Is there any way to make the link output easier to read so I can debug this?

Comment: If you've got device code that nvlink requires in a .cpp file, that's a problem.  I can only see `KeplerianImpact.o` and `Geodesy.o` in the compile command, so I don't know, just basing it on your statements.

Comment: I have `__constant__` values that I need in the cpp code that Geodesy needs. All Geodesy code is compiled `__host__ __device__` though. Do the locations of the constants make a difference?

Comment: Yes.  By default, nvcc ignores any code in a .cpp file and hands the entire file off to the host compiler.  I'm not really sure what's going on in your case, however, as the host compiler should have choked on the `__constant__` construct.  (it should also choke on `__host__ __device__`).  Nevertheless, if that is intended for the device, and is in a .cpp file, it could give rise to link issues.

Comment: I define `__constant__, __host__` and `__device__` to nothing if `__CUDACC__` is defined. This (I thought) would allow me to use the same classes and definitions for both cpp and cu files. I'll try an experiment by changing the extension and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Oops, I mean "if `__CUDACC__` is **not** defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.

I needed to define my functions in the correct files. For example, in `Foo.h`:

```
class Foo {
public:
    __host__ __device__
    Foo();
}
```

and the function definition in `Foo.cu` **not** `Foo.cpp` as I originally thought.

```
 Foo::Foo() {}
```

For the constant variables, I needed to implement a slightly different strategy.

Here is an example of the C++ class that I started with:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static double const epsilon;
    static void functionThatUsesEpsilon();
    /**/
}
```

Had to be converted to use the global namespace as the epsilon def'n

```
namespace foo {
    extern __constant__ double epsilon;
} 

class Foo {
public:
    // same stuff as before with the addition of this function
    __host__ __device__
    static inline double getEpsilon() {
#ifdef __CUDACC__
         return foo::epsilon;
#else
         return epsilon;
#endif
    }  

    static void functionThatUsesEpsilon() {
        if (bar < getEpsilon()) { // etc }
    }
};
```

The `ifdef` above will return the correct version of the variable for either the host or the device code. Everywhere I had referenced `Foo::epsilon` I needed to replace with `Foo::getEpsilon()` so the correct epsilon was returned.

Hope this helps someone in the future. Thanks to @RobertCrovella for getting me thinking.

Answer (score 5):

Use `c++filt` to demangle the names. For instance:

> $ c++filt _ZN5JARSS15KeplerianImpactC1ERKdS2_S2_S2_S2_S2_
>   JARSS::KeplerianImpact::KeplerianImpact(double const&, double const&, double const&, double const&, double const&, double const&)

Answer (score 2):

Faced this problem earlier, I guess you haven't linked the device object using device linker.

Generate relocatable code for the device by compiling as shown below (-dc is the device equivalent of -c, see the [manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda) for more information)

```
nvcc –arch=sm_21 –dc a.cu b.cu
```

Link the device parts of the code by calling nvlink or dlink before the final host link

```
nvlink -arch=sm_21 a.o b.o -o link.o (or)
nvcc –arch=sm_21 –dlink a.o b.o –o link.o
```

Finally form a executable using host compiler,

```
g++ a.o b.o link.o –L<path> -lcudart
```